# Where to get DLL for Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Devices

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, microsoft-expression

I'm trying to run this WebCam project which written in C#, WPF Application. The project I'm trying to run is on CodeProject website. [LINK](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285964/WPF-Webcam-Control) 
They didn't provide me with `Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Devices` DLL. I searched it online, I cannot find it.

```
using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Devices;
```

> ERROR: The Type or NameSpace name 'Expression' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'(are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Search the page for **Requirements** - The SDK download link is right there.

Comment: thanks. I downloaded Expression Encoder 4 into the bin/debug folder of the project i'm trying to run. Inside the Expression Encoder 4 that i downloaded, there was a 'Encoder_en.exe' I ran it and it prompted me to install Expression Encoder 4. I did. I ran the project again. Same Error.

Comment: Right click *references* in *solution explorer* and add the dll

Comment: I still don't know where that DLL is. I search all my computer (Win+Q). I also searched under Add Reference-->.Net and Add References-->COM
I could not find the DLL.

Comment: DAMN! Found it, it was installed in c:// although i ran it from bin/Debug. So the DLL was in the C://..Microsoft Expression folder

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Just a small question, so, when i downloaded an SDK, i got a DLL (in this situation) so what's the difference between SDK and DLL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so I had to look at the references section in the same CodeProject link i posted and download and install 'Expression Encoder 4' after that, depending on where that thing installed, the DLL file will be found there. Then just copy that DLL to your project and add to references.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.encoder.devices.aspx), you'll need Expression Studio. [Expression Studio is no longer available for sale as a stand-alone product](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/); however, [Expression Encoder 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18974) *is* available as a free download and should contain the dll you are looking for.

Comment: thanks. I downloaded Expression Encoder 4 into the bin/debug folder of the project i'm trying to run. Inside the Expression Encoder 4 that i downloaded, there was a 'Encoder_en.exe' I ran it and it prompted me to install Expression Encoder 4. I did. I ran the project again. Same Error.

Comment: Did you look in the Program Files folder that Expression Encoder installed into? I'm assuming you'll have to update your Visual Studio project to point to the location of that dll.