# Microsoft.Encoder.Expression.Utilities not found when I try to use the EncoderDevices.FindDevices() method. Am I missing this dependency?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am following this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285964/WPF-Webcam-Control?fid=1666019&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&prof=True&view=Normal&fr=1#xx0xx
When I run the program I always get the same error.
Error: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Utilities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

I tried to find that Utilities file but I couldn't find it. I checked the comments on the article and there were a couple of people with the same problem. I did change the Active solution platform to x86 as well but that did nothing.

```
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Devices;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;


namespace Webcam
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Collection<EncoderDevice> VideoDevices { get; set; }
        public Collection<EncoderDevice> AudioDevices { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;

            VideoDevices = 
EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Video);
            AudioDevices = 
EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Audio);
        }
 }
```

The error always occurs on the line
 VideoDevices = EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Video);

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283833/where-to-get-dll-for-microsoft-expression-encoder-devices. The link to the DLL can be found in the requirements section of your Codeproject link.

Comment: @ckuri I think that is a seperate issue because I have the Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Devices dll

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t see the different DLL names. I looked into the setup file with 7-zip and it contains an EnComn.cab file which contains an 8 MB large Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Utilities file which is missing the DLL extension but is clearly a .NET DLL. So I assume the DLL is somewhere on your hard drive although it may be missing the DLL extension.

Comment: Where is this setup file you mentioned?

Comment: The linked setup in the requirements section of your Codeproject link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27870

Comment: @ckuri Thank you so much it is finally working now. What I didn't realize was that installing the package for the webcam controls was not enough, even though it did contain the Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.dll I needed, I just installed the sdk and the project runs smoothly. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: The link appears to be broken...

Answer (score 0):

Download Microsoft Expression Encoder 4 : https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=18974

Install it on your system, so required dll will be install on your machine.
Now build your application and run. it will work.

Comment: The link doesn't work. Try this link: https://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Expression-Encoder-4/3000-18515_4-75450292.html